# Should I setup DFS Namespaces on each file/web server or on the domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, dfs-r

I have <s>a primary and alternate</s> multiple domain controllers setup in a Amazon VPC and multiple web servers setup that I want to share content and configuration.

Should I use the domain controller as the namespace server or just setup the namespace on the web server?

How would you setup the DFS-N to be fault tolerant in case the primary server goes down?  Do I have to use clustering?

Comment: 1. Stop calling the domain controllers primary and alternate. They aren't. 2. You would/should host the namespace on both DC's to achieve redundancy of the namespace. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730736

Comment: Your title asks about replication, but your question doesn't.

Comment: Fixed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need clustering. If you're using an AD integrated namespace, then the namespace info is stored in AD, allowing for easy recoverability. You can have one or more servers host the namespace for redundancy and nothing special like clustering needs to be done. It *just works*